# jni deleteRef for jclass and jobject

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

is this right way of deleteing reference for jclass and jobject

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_method(JNIEnv *env,jobject, jobject objArray)
{
    int n = env->GetArrayLength(objArray);

    for (int i = 0; i<n ; ++i)
    {
        jobject sObject = env->GetObjectArrayElement(objArray, i);
        jclass sObjectClass = env->GetObjectClass(sObject);

        dosomething(sObjectClass, sObject);

        env->DeleteLocalRef(sObject);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(sObjectClass);
    }
```

Comment: Yes for local references this is correct. And it should prevent a reference table overflow.

Comment: Why do you need `GetObjectClass` inside the loop though? Do you expect the elements in the array to be of different types?

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer:**

Yes it is a right way. The call `DeleteLocalRef` is not necessary but it is useful if the `objArray` is big or if the function execution time is long.

**Longer answer:**

Oracle reference documentation states

> Primitive types, such as integers, characters, and so on, are copied
>   between Java and native code. Arbitrary Java objects, on the other
>   hand, are passed by reference. The VM must keep track of all objects
>   that have been passed to the native code, so that these objects are
>   not freed by the garbage collector. The native code, in turn, must
>   have a way to inform the VM that it no longer needs the objects. In
>   addition, the garbage collector must be able to move an object
>   referred to by the native code.

So any object that native code use must be marked as eligible for garbage collection from native code point of view when native code does need the object anymore. JNI has two types of references - global and local references. The references retrieved from `GetObjectArrayElement` and `GetObjectClass` are local because:

> All Java objects returned by JNI functions are local references.

VM automatically frees all local references when a native function returns. So it is not necessary to free these references by `DeleteLocalRef` in most cases because VM frees them automatically.

But if there are a lot of local references required in one function call or the call takes long time then it is worth to free them explicitly immediately when they are not needed and do not wait to function returns. Freeing helps VM to do better memory management.

Comment: If your native code is at the bottom of the call stack, you *must* release local references or the JVM can run out.  You can convert them to global references if you keep them around.  How can native code be at the bottom of the stack?  If your native code created the JVM, or your native code made a native thread.

Comment: @Wheezil: You are correct, but I assume the question is not about situation when native code is at the bottom of the stack. At least the code in the question indicates it is a native function called from jvm,

Comment: Yes of course you are right.  I should have noted that my comment is the rare exception rather than the rule.